# Facebook banners for pages

Tags: facebook-pages

With the upcoming transition of Facebook pages to the ["new profile page look"](http://mashable.com/2011/02/10/facebook-pages-redesign-2/) I would like to create banners for my pages.

With the **new profile** it was easy, as there's a mutitude of applications out to do that: upload an image and create a banner. Some applications are more spammy than others, but still, it's possible.

For **pages** however I haven't found an application yet – so I tried to make a banner on my own. I took an image in 485x68 and split that into five parts – all uploaded into a new album to the page. And they appear in the banner, but not in the order I intended, but rather - on page load - in a random manner.

How can I prevent this? And why is that?

And before re-inventing the wheel: is there an application that does banners for pages? And which doesn't re-order at random?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot. Facebook randomizes the order of pictures on pages. I would suggest a collage-type of banner. That way, whatever order, it still looks pretty sweet.